# Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation. _Scary was 0x30

Tags: c++11, model, nodes, directx, directx-11

i got an issue with specific error Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation.
_Scary was 0x30.
i m trying to load a terrain with a model loaded from assimp and i keep getting this exception

```
 const auto _Scary = _Get_scary();
    _Tree_find_result<_Nodeptr> _Result{{_Scary->_Myhead->_Parent, _Tree_child::_Right}, _Scary->_Myhead};
    _Nodeptr _Trynode = _Result._Location._Parent;
```

Comment: Without seeing a [mre] there's very little we can do to help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them.